# Flyway 1.7 to 3.X upgrade

Tags: flyway

What is the proper upgrade path for Flyway 1.7 to 3.X?  Currently my migration files are prefixed with a single underscore (V1_foobar.sql).  We use Flyway with embedded derby.

I know the sql seperator has changed to `__`, which seems to be compensated by the Java API.  But I have no issue with renaming the files as well.  More or less I'm looking for a command line script that I can run before starting the server to migrate the metadata table on older deployment.  If it can optionally rename the entries that use `_` to using the `__` format, that would be great too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the Flyway 3.0 release notes (http://flywaydb.org/documentation/releaseNotes.html#flyway-3.0), you must upgrade to 2.3 first, before upgrading to 3.X.

For the 2.3 upgrade you will have to rename your files to use the standard __ separator. As of 3.0 this is freely configurable using the `flyway.separator`property.

Comment: So I changed the migration files to using two underscores __, rebuilt my source and restarted. The following code get's called at start up: 
``` 
        Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
        flyway.setDataSource(datasource);
        flyway.migrate();
```
It seems this throws an Exception though.
`com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to upgrade metadata to the new Flyway 2.0 format as description is now mandatory and these migrations do not have one: 1.initial.version, `...

Thoughts?

Comment: Yes. Flyway 1.7 used to accept letters in the version, which is the reason why you could get by with using a single underscore. For V1_foobar.sql , the info in your metadata table probably looks like this: version=1.foobar , description=null => 2 solutions: manually patch metadata table or drop it and use baseline() to recreate it with Flyway 3.1

Comment: Interesting.  I guess I could write a simple SQL statement to split the version field and update the contents.

If I went the baseline path, would the older scripts still be recognized by the version table?  What about new installations?

Comment: The baseline route would mark the db as being at version X, ignoring all scripts <= X. New installations would run all scripts (after they have been renamed with __) as usual.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm going to go with the baseline route at 3.0.  I'll just run a script before I start the server, that nukes the SCHEMA_VERSIONS table and calls Flyway's baseline at that top version.